# How to get variables out of a get odata call method

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

What is the best way to get variables out of a get odata call. I have this code in a method where i want to work with the variable 'id', which i am getting with the odata call. I tried already callbacks but i cant get the right way. Do you have a solution for this? I tried also to put the call in an extra function, but then i get the problem that by return variable is undefined i a cant access it.

Update / additional:

I have a method where i am doing some odata updates and inserts. in my code below i am getting a id. this id i need in the next step for another odata update as parameter. My problem is that i cant work with the var id in the next steps of my code, because its only accessable in the oModel {} section.

```
oModel.read("/ZDEMA_LENDINGS2Set", {
    urlParameters: {
        "$select": "Id",
        "$top": 1
    },
    success: function(oData, oResponse) {
        console.log("Data", oData);
        console.log("Response", oResponse); 
        var id = oData.results[0].Id;
    },
    error: function(oError) {
        console.log("Error", oError);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put a variable outside of this call and assign it in the callback
Like let id; and inside success cb assign id=oData.results[0].id

Comment: i think this isnt working, i tried it before. i think its because the asynchronously of the odata calls

Comment: Whenever you get the response you will be assigning the data that's not an issue may be give us a reproduce what you are doing?

Comment: I have a method where i am doing some odata updates and inserts. in my code above i am getting a id. this id i need in the next step for another odata update as parameter. My problem is that i cant work with the var id in the next steps of my code, because its only accessable in the oModel {} section.

Answer (score 1):

Since this an UI5 app, I suggest using a local JSON Model and set the value as property.

```
this.getView().getModel('myLocalModel').setProperty("lendingId", oData.results[0].Id)
```

This has the advantage that you can use the two way databinding and or change listeners.
Alternative approach is to fire an event on the event bus.